# X509CertificateStore.FindCertificateBySubjectName does not work in x64?

Tags: .net, x509certificate

I am using the following code:

```
 store = X509CertificateStore.LocalMachineStore(X509CertificateStore.RootStore);

            store.OpenRead();

             Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection certs =
                store.FindCertificateBySubjectName("CN=my cert bla bla");

            if (certs.Count == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("Not found!");
            }
```

When i set my platform target to x86, it works... if i put it x64 (or Any CPU) it says not found. 
I'm confused, any help?

Thanks very much.

Comment: And this only happens in a 64bit Machine...

Comment: Is there some reason you're using the WSE version of these objects instead of the ones inside System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a bug in the Find methods of this class which prevents them from working in x64.  Specifically they're using IntPtrs to send data to native methods.

As a work around you can loop through the certificates in the store and do your comparison manually (see sample below), though even in the hack it would be better to use the thumbprint or serial number.

A better solution is to re-plumb your application to use the supported class System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store to access your certificates.  This class does work in 64 bit mode.

```
foreach(X509Certificate cert in store.Certificates)
{
    if (cert != null && cert.Subject.Contains("CN=my cert bla bla"))
        return cert;
}
Console.WriteLine("Not found!");
```